# Guide to building a Linux Standard Operating Environment (SOE)

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to build a Linux Standard Operating Environment (SOE) using CentOS 7 and unfortunately, I couldn't get much information on the web, other than the theoretical guides.

Are there any step-by-step instructions freely available on building Linux SOEs?

Comment: What are you looking for, beyond a standard install of CentOS ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not very sure. I would like to standardize a CentOS 7 in a Dev environment and then possibly template the build which can then be used to deploy. Secondly, a bit of hardening.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Operating_Environment

Unless you have many computers OSs to install there is no point in creating a custom image / installer. ( an install script is a better ROI for less frequent installs)

You can roll your own anyway you please or use distribution specific tools like

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax

> The recommended approach to creating Kickstart files is to perform a manual installation on one system first. After the installation completes, all choices made during the installation are saved into a file named anaconda-ks.cfg, located in the /root/ directory on the installed system. You can then copy this file, make any changes you need, and use the resulting configuration file in further [automated] installations

Or

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apb.html

Or

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO